# Django - want to use inspectdb to get only one table. Using MS SQL Server

Tags: django

I've been testing the inspectdb with django 4.0.  If I do "python manage.py inspectdb --database MSDatabase", it tries to bring all table info into the model.  Is there a way to select only few or one tables?

The DB server is MS SQL Server. The database is MSDatabase, the schema is MySchema, and the table name is MYTBL.

I tried "python manage.py inspectdb --database MSDatabase MYTBL" and got the table not found error.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the name of the table to do it.

```
python manage.py inspectdb table1
```

Or multiple tables

```
python manage.py inspectdb table1 table2
```

Here's the the [link to inspectdb documention for Django 4.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/django-admin/#inspectdb).

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked.

```
python manage.py inspectdb --database MyDb table1
```